# PHP onload function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to figure out a way to load something in PHP only when the page has been fully loaded.

What I have is:

```
echo "
 <td colspan='5'>
 <div id='div".$x."' class='targetDiv' style='visibility: hidden'>

 <center>".load($data['download_url']);"</center>

 </div>
";
```

I need the .load bit to only be inserted or initialized when the rest of the page is fully loaded. I'v read ways of doing this with jQuery and Ajax, but couldn't make them work.

Comment: define `couldn't make them work.`

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, there is no way to do something on the server when the page has loaded, as it would be too late by then.

Comment: what was your code with `jQuery` and what problems occured while using it?

Comment: couldn't make them work - didn't have the knowledge of how to make them work. The whole problem is, that the .load is a flash player. I have around 20 of them on the page and If someone has a laggy internet - they all start playing for a split second as they all have autoplay = on. Once loaded they go quiet as they are .hidden

Comment: If that is the case, then you can just use Javascript/jQuery to write out the appropriate HTML after the page has loaded. There's no need to load the HTML from the server *after* page load.

Comment: ... or even simpler: just only set `autoplay` to `true` *after* page load (if the flash component you use allows this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do such a thing, without AJAX.
Check [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, it has full and simple documentation.

Anyway, you have to write something like this (there are some pretty bad practices, but it's only for example):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://yoursite.com/yourpage.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#paste-result-here').html(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="paste-result-here"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And php yourpage.php:

```
echo "
 <div id='div{$x}' class='targetDiv' style='visibility: hidden'>
   <center>{$data['download_url']}</center>
 </div> 
";
```